# Request for new shortcuts to the new help pages

Tags: feature-request

So, we now have [help](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help) instead of the FAQ. Not really a fan of the new layout, in my opinion it's harder to find info. Regardless, it would be nice to have some proper shortcuts to the specific pages of help.

As some users here may know, I linked to the FAQ a lot. I used the shortcut [FAQ] to link to the FAQ quickly and easily. It would be great to have some similarly short and simple links to link to specific parts of the new Help pages.

My suggestions:

```
Comment input == Comment parser output
----------------------------------------
[help]        == [help](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help)
[ontopic]     == [on topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
[dontask]     == [don't ask](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)
[closed]      == [closed](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)
[reputation]  == [reputation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)
```

Recognizing capitals in the comment input, and converting appropriately for the output would be nice too.

Comment: I like this. Also, it would be great if this related issue was finally fixed: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/999/why-can-i-not-link-directly-to-faq-anchors